# Pushwoosh create message get 200, but say UnknownDevices

Tags: pushwoosh

My system running at least two years. Most push notification requests got 200. But, recently, I found I got 500 frequently.

Nealy 10% push notifications got 500.

Please HELP!!!

I have resend the problem messages, every thing is fine.

Example:
Request is:

```
{
  "request": {
    "application": "3DXXX-59XXX",
    "username": "MyXXXXX",
    "password": "********",
    "notifications": [
      {
        "send_date": "now",
        "content": {
          "en": "Subscriber ID. 9000  Close  User 01"
        },
        "link": "",
        "data": {
          "userID": "12345"
        },
        "wp_type": "",
        "wp_background": "",
        "wp_count": "",
        "ios_badges": 51,
        "ios_sound": "short-tone.caf",
        "devices": [
          "APA91bHZHEhIMjVYwxyMk-4-YObazHfcxlQq7CmYto930nuIqHlQGCdzUQsnDcnHTB78wUcTlm-qhV3ipMqe9HO3kTqD9j_zgzSUUAdoGK0fbeRRGMNn69Z63BlQ9RqIdioZ4J2NFA0DLOUkroImk-it8p_3Glr5bRlnrl1_wT3ycXfsgvQZq4g"
        ],
        "page_id": "0",
        "android_sound": "five_sectoneone"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Response is: 
{"status_code":500,"status_message":"Invalid devices list"}

==============================================================
========================= Update =============================

After I upgrade Pushwoosh API from V1.2 to V1.3, the problem is gone.

However, new problem comes.

My sample is:

request :

```
{
  "request": {
    "application": "3DXXX-59XXX",
    "auth": "*********WqLiS5ZM2****************************************9eib******",
    "notifications": [
      {
        "send_date": "now",
        "content": {
          "en": "Jones Residence Tue,17Jul 12:12 Test from Robbie......."
        },
        "link": "",
        "data": {
          "userID": "12345"
        },
        "wp_type": "",
        "wp_background": "",
        "wp_count": "",
        "ios_badges": 39,
        "ios_sound": "short-tone.caf",
        "devices": [
          "298eeXXXXa26849cc77da16adXXXXc1c801df12e79bad1e724829aXXXXcbe07d"  //I hashed real ID here
        ],
        "page_id": "0",
        "android_sound": "five_sectoneone"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Response is:

```
{
  "status_code": 200,
  "status_message": "OK",
  "response": {
    "Messages": [
      "D954-3C45B1AA-AA6293E5"
    ],
    "UnknownDevices": {
      "D954-3C45B1AA-AA6293E5": [
        "298eeXXXXa26849cc77da16adXXXXc1c801df12e79bad1e724829aXXXXcbe07d" //I hashed real ID here
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any sample of the request that failed? Thanks!
Pushwoosh team.

Comment: @shader I am updating my post. I got {"status_code":500,"status_message":"Invalid devices list"}

Comment: Looking into that. Will keep you posted. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you already wrote the question in Pushwoosh community. I'll post the answer here as well.

The "UnknownDevice" warning indicates that the push token that you have put in the "devices" section of the createMessage request isn't in our databases.

There are several reasons for that:

1) The application was deleted from the device.

2) The push token was renewed. APNs/GCM/etc. tends to change push tokens from time to time, and we remove outdated push tokens from our servers. (This happens VERY rarely)

3) There is a misprint in your request. (I'm sure this is not the case)

Please note that in order to keep your userbase up-to-date you can use getUnregisteredDevices method, which would return a last thousand of removed push tokens. You will need to call this on a regular basis.

P.S. https://community.pushwoosh.com/questions/998/pushwoosh-create-message-get-200-but-says-unknowndevices
P.P.S. Do not use 1.2 API, it is very old and will be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you use wrong device token. Don't use device UUID. You can send device token to your database after put it deviceArray in the Java code.
Edit PushwooshiOS.js file;

```
pushNotification.registerDevice(
    function(status)
    {
        var deviceToken = status['deviceToken'];
        console.warn('registerDevice: ' + deviceToken);

        $.ajax({
            url : "http://ip:port/deviceid/"+deviceToken,
            dataType : "json",
            success : function(a, b, c) {
                console.log("send tokens to server after call t in your json array");    
            },
            error : function(a, b, c) {
                console.log("err a ", a);
                console.log("err b ", b);
                console.log("err c ", c);
                console.log("err c ", c);
            }
        });
        onPushwooshiOSInitialized(deviceToken);
    },
    function(status)
    {
        console.warn('failed to register : ' + JSON.stringify(status));
        //alert(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
    }
);
```

Java code

```
String method = "createMessage";
URL url = new URL(PUSHWOOSH_SERVICE_BASE_URL + method);
JSONArray deviceArray = new JSONArray();
// put your device tokens
deviceArray.put(deviceToken);
JSONArray notificationsArray = new JSONArray()
        .put(new JSONObject().put("send_date", "now")   
                             .put("content", "A test push")
                             .put("devices",deviceArray));
JSONObject requestObject = new JSONObject()
        .put("application", APPLICATION_CODE)
        .put("auth", AUTH_TOKEN)
        .put("notifications", notificationsArray);
JSONObject mainRequest = new JSONObject().put("request", requestObject);
JSONObject response = SendServerRequest.sendJSONRequest(url, mainRequest.toString());
```